# BroadCast Receiver Battery Status error

Tags: java, android, eclipse

i'm trying to use in my project a broadcast receiver which listens to battery status of charging/not charging and throw a toast in each of the options .
every time i change the charger status in the app ,the app crash.
(if i start the app with the charger connected it's show me the right toast
but when i uncharge the phone the app crashes)
here is the code
thanks in advance

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
IntentFilter ifilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);
Intent batteryStatus = this.registerReceiver(null, ifilter);
int status = batteryStatus.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_STATUS, -1);

boolean isCharging = status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_CHARGING ||
                     status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_FULL;

    if(isCharging==true){

        Toast.makeText(this, "Charging", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else{
        Toast.makeText(this, "Charger not connected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

UPDATE 
i'm having an hard time to understand what i suppose to do.
i'm pretty new so be patient with me :)

here is the code i made

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity  {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            checkBatteryState(null);


        public void checkBatteryState(View sender) {
            IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);
            Intent batteryStatus = registerReceiver(null, filter);

            int chargeState = batteryStatus.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_STATUS, -1);
            String strState;

            switch (chargeState) {
                case BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_CHARGING:
                case BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_FULL:
                    strState = "charging";
                    Toast.makeText(this, strState, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    break;
                default:
                    strState = "not charging";
                    Toast.makeText(this, strState, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean the App crashes. What is logged. What exception is given. What do you expect to happen? Give more info when asking a question please

Comment: i can't check what shown in the log cat because it's on a real phone. i'm not using emulator(not working on my mac).i just want to get a toast every time the charger is connected/disconnected to the phone

Comment: If the phone is connected to the computer via a usb cable and USB debugging is enabled, you can see stuff in the logcat.

Comment: The problem is really simple why i can't check the log cat. the app only crashes when their is a change with the charger. which means that if i start the phone connected to the usb-pc i can see the toast "charging" but when i want to uncharge the phone and see the toast not charging" the app crash. on the other hand... when i start the app not connected i get the toast "not charging"and when i connect it to the usb-pc the app crashes again.. before i can see the log cat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBroadcastReceiver/article.html

is this what you're using?

Maybe you haven't ensured your Intent is sticky.

My advice would be not to use a registerreceiver with a null argument.

Try this method for creating a broadcastreceiver:
[How to send data to another app which is not started](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28198686/how-to-send-data-to-another-app-which-is-not-started/28198968#28198968)

put your Toasts in the onReceive() function.

Answer (score 0):

The code is not actually registering a receiver, just getting a sticky broadcast. If the broadcast has never been sent the this will return null which will cause a NPE in the remaining code.