# how to render view in android based on the data received from server?

Tags: java, android

I am new to android development. I am trying to build basic shopping cart. I want to know how can I render view based on the data (product details) received from server. Because I will make a call to server in AsyncTask and I will have to wait for the data and then only I will be able to render them. So, I couldn't be able to figure out how would I manage it? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use a broadcastreceiver in the activity that contains the view you want to render.
Look at this answer:

[How to send data to another app which is not started](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28198686/how-to-send-data-to-another-app-which-is-not-started/28198968#28198968)

Render your view in the onReceive() function of your BroadcastReceiver.

Answer (score 0):

As you said you're going to use `AsyncTask`, you can render any view you want in the `onPostExecute()` method, which runs on the `UIThread`.

Answer (score 0):

I would display a progressbar before you execute the AsyncTask and then AsyncTask's onPostExecute() method you would hide the progressbar and update the views with the requested data.